# How to keep Virtual Keyboard hidden on an Edit box in Delphi

Tags: delphi, firemonkey, virtual-keyboard

I start using Delphi 10.4.1 for Android hand held terminals. Some of the terminals comes with a numeric keypad on device itself. I would like to hide/don't want to show Virtual keyboard at all for some of the Edit boxes but some of the edit boxes I need to be able to show keyboard as I need to type alphanumeric characters.

I found just one solution which disable the virtual keyboard completely which I need in some other component like ListView search box etc.

I would be grateful if anyone can help me.

Thanks

Comment: Set VkAutoShowMode (FMX.Types unit)  global variable to TVKAutoShowMode.Never if you do not want the VK to show. Be sure to change it to TVKAutoShowMode.DefinedBySystem when you *do* want it to show

Comment: Thats worked.. Thanks a lot